# libreoffice Command to compress the pdf file

Tags: node.js, pdf, compression, libreoffice

Am trying write `nodejs` code to compress the `pdf` and came across the `libreoffice` support the `pdf` utilities but I don't know the command

Now am using `GS` to compress the file but the problem with GS is it won't work in concurrent request, please find below gs script

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out_put in_put
```

please help me to do this code using `libreoffice` command line so the same command I run form.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion saying that libreoffice does only compress the images.

Comment: Is there any libreoffice command to do so?